# Laravel foreach same product multiple

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have some problems with Laravel foreach. Foreach as foreach is working fine, but I have foreached multiple same items that I need to put in one.
For example
I have product that can be booked for every day, and if I book it for 10 days it will foreach it 10 times that same product. I need to develop function that will take all prices per person, quantity and total price and sum it and show it in one row. It's giving correct information's and prices, I just need to sum all of that data and put it in one. Of course I need to foreeach all products, cause it can be 2 products 10 days, and foreach it every product 10 times.

If I want to check is same id for that product I have to put `$change->rate_id`

Here is code that i'm using in blade

```
@foreach($extras_changes as $iKey => $change)
               @php $extraId = uniqid(); @endphp
               <tr>
                  <td class="cell-product">
                     <div class="product-body">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$extraId}}">
                           <h4 class="modal-title product-title">{{$change->offerable->name}}</h4>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-total col-md-2 text-right">
                     <span class="price">
                     @php
                        $price = _amount($change->price, $change->currency, get_display_currency());
                     @endphp
                     @include('extranet.amount', ['data'=> $price])
                     </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                     {{$change->quantity}}
                  </td>
                  <td class="cell-total col-md-2 text-right">
                     <span class="price">
                     @php
                        $amount = _amount($change->price * $change->quantity, $change->currency, get_display_currency());
                        $amountChange += $amount['value'];
                     @endphp
                     @include('extranet.amount', ['data'=> $amount])
                     </span>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               @include('frontend.planner.change_modal_new', ['id' => $extraId])
               @endforeach
```

I will give you one more example to be more specific.
I have table like:

Product Name    |    Price Per Person  |   Quantity   |   Total

1. Dinner       |       EUR 9,50       |      2     |     EUR 19,00
2. Dinner       |       EUR 9,50     |        2      |    EUR 19,00
3. Dinner       |       EUR 9,50      |       2      |    EUR 19,00
4. Dinner       |       EUR 9,50      |       2      |    EUR 19,00
5. Dinner     |        EUR 9,50     |        2     |     EUR 19,00

I need to show it like:

Product Name    |    Price Per Person  |   Quantity  |    Total

1. Dinner      |        EUR 9,50        |     10    |     EUR 95,00

Comment: fetch the data using `->groupBy('product_name', 'price', 'qty', 'total')`

Comment: Sorry I don't know where to put this code. I can't find controller for this.

Comment: How about, for the subtotals using the aggregate method like so: `->sum('quantity')` or `->sum('total')`. Also, as an aside to the question: why do you store the total? Why not just have an accessor method on the model that returns `$this->quantity * $this->price_per_person`?

Comment: That's the problem.. it's not my call how to do that :)

Comment: where does `$extras_changes` comes from?

Comment: Fixed by my self.